# By using PhoneGap can we convert iphone app to android app?

Tags: iphone, android

Can we build an iphone app and convert the application to the android application using phonegap framework?

I have been through various links.

We basically need to develop a webapp for that and that can be converted to an android app or an iphone app respectively.

I am an iphone application developer and i am not at all familiar to android.

Links or example code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhoneGap will not enable you to "port" an existing iphone application to Android. However, if you develop an application within the PhoneGap framework (which means using html, css and javascript), you will be able to deploy it on multiple mobile platforms such as iPhone, Android, Nokia, Blackberry, etc.

The downside is that you will eventually be developing a packaged mobile website - your application consist of html pages, css styling and javascript behaviour/logic, combined whith access to phone internals such as gps, disk, database, camera, etc. It will usually not "feel" fully native on most platforms. For example, you will not be using the system's "native" ListView.

There are javascript libraries such as JQuery-mobile, JQTouch, etc, that make your application look nicer on mobile devices, but it's still not as good as the native experience.

Comment: i did not get your second para description can you please reply in details.

Comment: What will you both prefer Phone gap or developing an specific app using there respective platforms(iphone for iphone apps etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The app you build will not be a native Android or IPhone app but a HTML Web App wrapped in the PhoneGap wrapper and packaged into a native app. So yes you can build for both platforms as long as you build a Web App

Edit -(a Web App is just a plain html/css/javascript + server-side(php, asp etc) website)

Comment: I wanted to know are there any links or example code for developing such an app which will be compatible on the android.

Comment: You need to build a website, that is all a Web App is. Here is a good link http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596805784/

Comment: its an book i want how can you  built an application as shown in the following link
http://groupaware.mobi/iphone/#_Samples

Comment: Come on! you're making me work for this:) http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596805784/ch02.html#ch02_id35817468
or
http://code.google.com/p/iui/

Comment: What will you both prefer Phone gap or developing an specific app using there respective platforms(iphone for iphone apps etc.)