# PhoneGap - Platform conversion from iphone to android

Tags: android, iphone, html, cordova, cross-platform

I have developed a Phone Gap application using [this link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/index.html).

Application is running like a charm on i Phone. But now I want to run this phone gap application on android. I googled it but cant find any thing.

I know there must be a way for platform conversion of phone gap application, but I don't know how.

EDIT : I have searched for platform conversion  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232375/by-using-phonegap-can-we-convert-iphone-app-to-android-app) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038467/choosing-between-mobile-app-platform-i-e-phonegap-and-native-code-for-2d-game).

One more thing I came to know about it that phonegap is providing facility of platform conversion. we can upload an iPhone build and they will send us android build after conversion. link for the same is [here](https://build.phonegap.com/), but I don't know how to use those files. As I am having mac machine and I want to create an android build.

Or is there any other way to develop phonegap application ???

Anyone can tell me how can I perform platform conversion ???

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you developed a html, jquery and css based application, you can do the platform conversion with a minimal changes in the code.

If you interacted with the mobile like alarm, notifications, sensors, display..etc., You cannot do the conversion.

Comment: I have implemented acceleration, notification, capture, camera , connection type and Location in my application. Is there any way so that while creating build a phonegap will ask the platform and build is created in that platform.....

Comment: You cannot do that. Already you are doing cross platform application development with html and java script. You have to develop application separately for every mobile plaforms.